# unable to make the ScrollView and textView (added programmatically) visible in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I was working on an android project where I have to write data from JSONArray. I tried to use TextView for each of the Array Input. so I used to code to add a scrollView on my existing layout and add a TextView init. The codes working perfectly without any error however, there is nothing in the UI when I compiled it. (In my mobile) Later, I tried to add another TextView to the existing LinearLayout instead of the ScrollView, it did not work that time either. I checked other questions and forums and it seemed to me that I have done/wrote everything they did, I still could not find my errors.

**UPDATE 1**: I have added the ScrollView inside another LinearLayout and keep another LinearLayout inside it. The TextView is being added inside the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView. The outer LinearLayout hold another TextView just post the exception log (my avd kernel crashed).

**UPDATE 2** I have made the scrollView's height WRAP_CONTENT and added four other TextView underneath it. Now, the app is loading is showing a considerable gap between the Top TextView and the last TextView groups. but still, ScrollView is not showing anything.

My code is **updated** & given below:

Java code:

```
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    LinearLayout mainLinear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);

    try {
        LinearLayout linear =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scroll_container);
        linear.setBackgroundColor(0xABCDEF);


        //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ));
            tv.setTextSize(25);
            //tv.setId(1);
            tv.setTextColor(0x000000);
            tv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tv.setText("I am serial " + 0 + "\n" + "is there something      more");
            linear.addView(tv);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ));
        tv1.setTextSize(25);
        //tv.setId(1);
        tv1.setTextColor(0x000000);
        tv1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tv1.setText("I am serial 3 " + 1 + "\n" + "is there something more");
        linear.addView(tv1);



        //tv.append("my name is apple " + 0 + "\n");

            TextView tv5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv5.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
               ));
                tv5.setTextSize(25);
               //tv.setId(1);
                tv5.setTextColor(0x000000);
                tv5.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                tv5.setText("Linear Layout e" + 0 + "\n");
                mainLinear.addView(tv5);




        // }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        t1.setText("<><>"+e);
    }
```

My Layout XML file:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/mainLinear">

<TextView android:text="Word: Monkey Kaka"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="Test 1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test 2"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test 3"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test 4"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was giving wrong hexValue for background in all cases. I changed the Layout Parameters to Linear from ViewGroup ( I dont know why, found it in a tutorial ). and finally I used an array of TextView instead of creating an object repeatedly.

Thanks for your help :)

```
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    LinearLayout mainLinear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLinear);

    try {
        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scroll_container);
        linear.setBackgroundColor(0xABCDEFFE);

        TextView []tv = new TextView[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            tv[i] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            tv[i].setLayoutParams(params);

            tv[i].setTextSize(25);
            tv[i].setId(i);
            tv[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv[i].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tv[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv[i].setText("I am serial 4 " + i + "\n" + "is there something more");
            linear.addView(tv[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        t1.setText(value+"<><>"+e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollView` widget can host only one direct child.

Your layout should look like this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

Then from your code you can add `TextView`s into the `LinearLayout` :

```
LinearLayout scrollContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scroll_container);
scrollContainer.addView(tv);
```

You should take a look at the `LogCat`. It may be telling you that:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

From `ScrollView:245` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/ScrollView.java#ScrollView):

```
@Override
public void addView(View child) {
    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ScrollView can host only one direct child");
    }

    super.addView(child);
}
```

**Edit:** (see third comment)
That is what will happen when you do `mainLinear.addView(tv1);`.
You can test it in a `res/layout/scroll_test.xml` in the Android Studio layout `Preview`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="me.ibtehaz.greapp.showWord"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinear">
    <TextView android:text="Word: Monkey Kaka"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 3" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test 4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now if you set the `ScrollView` layout height to `wrap_content`, you will see those 4 `TextView`s appear.

It is more a UI Design problem than a code problem.

Comment: The `mainLinear.addView(tv1);` may not "work". Since the `ScrollView` height is set to `match_parent`, the `ScrollView` will fill the space left by the first `TextView` (`@+id/t1)`. Anything you add below the `ScrollView` will be added out of the screen.

Comment: What do you try to do by adding these `TextView`s below the ScrollView?

Comment: I did what you wrote in the XML above and now the UI is showing a considering gap which indicating that the there is a ScrollView but there is no Text in it.

Comment: The last XML was not a "you should do". It is here to show you that `match_parent` on the `ScrollView` will fill the entire screen and `wrap_content` will just make the `ScollView` unusable. This is definitly a UI Design problem

Comment: I will try to show data. I will load the JSON data from files or server and load them in the page. My teammate & friend have 20 layouts for 20 different files which I am trying to reduce into six where all the files will be loaded in one layout depending on which button is being clicked and later, getting Intent data.

Comment: I understood that. I tried that and I am keeping that to understand the ScrollView is working. what I dont understand is, why ScrollView is not showing the Texts I have added from source code in linearLayout.